# Query to find the a collection with a number in it

Tags: mongodb

So I have a query in which we are supposed to find all the numbers which contain "9".
One of my entries is as follows:
`

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63945fb591a4f6443e8edbeb"
  },
  "customer_id": {
    "$oid": "63945f6191a4f6443e8edbea"
  },
  "customer_name": [
    "Spike",
    "Takahashi"
  ],
  "customer_age": {
    "$numberLong": "23"
  },
  "mobile_no.": [
    "7898654324",
    "9232111456"
  ]
}
```

`

Now I know `$regex` is used to do the same for strings but I can't seem to get the output which i want. Probably coz i am using array and numbers as strings. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Given the document you show, what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: i want all the details of the person who has 9 in their numbers. nothing complicated

Comment: In which fields do you want to look for `9`?

Comment: oh thats my bad i thought i specified it. `mobile_no.`

Answer (score 1):

> Now I know $regex is used to do the same for strings but I can't seem to get the output which i want. Probably coz i am using array and numbers as strings.

Actually I don't think the problem is the array here. MongoDB has pretty intuitive syntax for specifying that you want to match any item in the array. In general, something like this would work:

```
> db.foo.find()
[ 
  { _id: 1, x: [ '123', '456' ] }, 
  { _id: 2, x: [ '789', '000' ] } 
]
> db.foo.find({x:/9/})
[ 
  { _id: 2, x: [ '789', '000' ] } 
]
```

Why do I say "in general" and why didn't I use your exact sample document? It's because the field name of interest currently ends in a "`.`" character. Continuing on the theme of MongoDB syntax, the "`.`" character is what the database typically uses to denote nested fields:

```
> db.foo.find({'x.y':'abc'})
[ 
  { _id: 3, x: { y: 'abc', z: 0 } } 
]
```

You can read more about querying nested fields using dot notation [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field).

The trailing dot in the field name (`mobile_no.`) is sort of confusing the database. We can see in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BgXXA2ESPrJ) that a regex similar to the one above (just using the slightly more verbose syntax due to a limitation of the playground) fails to return any results:

```
db.collection.find({
  "mobile_no.": {
    $regex: "9"
  }
})

no document found
```

But if we remove the "`.`" character from the document and the query, the document is retrieved as expected:

```
db.collection.find({
  "mobile_no": {
    $regex: "9"
  }
})

[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("63945fb591a4f6443e8edbeb"),
    "customer_age": NumberLong(23),
    "customer_id": ObjectId("63945f6191a4f6443e8edbea"),
    "customer_name": [
      "Spike",
      "Takahashi"
    ],
    "mobile_no": [
      "7898654324",
      "9232111456"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7xR1cSH1AyF).

MongoDB improved the way that we can interact with field names containing periods and dollar signs last year as outlined [on this page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/). While you technically *could* query this document using those new techniques, it is quite convoluted and will not perform efficiently. The query would look something like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $reduce: {
      input: {
        $getField: "mobile_no."
      },
      initialValue: false,
      in: {
        $or: [
          "$$value",
          {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: "$$this",
              regex: "9"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LpFe6mrfbgZ)

Personally I think it is much more straightforward to remove the trailing "`.`" from the field name as it does not provide any particular value being stored in the backend database anyway.